# Can't get NDEF_DISCOVERED action when opening the application with NFC tag

Tags: java, android, nfc

So I programmed an NFC tag to launch my application that I'm currently working on. I used the following service to do that:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc&hl=en

What I want to do is to switch from one activity to another whenever the NFC tag opens my application.

Under the manifest tag in my AndroidManifest.xml I have:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" android:required="true" />`

And my MainActivity looks like this:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Since the NFC tag opens the MainActivity first, I want to see whether it's been opened by NFC. If it has, switch to another activity.

The problem is that `getIntent().getAction()` always returns `android.intent.action.MAIN` while I'm expecting `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`.

At the moment I'm performing this check (debugging basically) under `onResume()` method with the following code:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    System.out.println(getIntent().getAction());
}
```

And I've tried performing this check under `onCreate()` and `onStart()` methods. All of them return  `android.intent.action.MAIN` result while I expect `android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED`.

I'm fresh in Android development and I'm just trying to make this work for a small prototype. Would appreciate if you guys could help me!

**Edit: I got it working! I researched this question a lot and I believe that my NFC tag needed some extra data of a text/plain type (I did not specify this mimeType before as well so seems like it's mandatory). I also had put NDEF_DISCOVERED under LAUNCHER category while trying to debug the application and then changed it back to DEFAULT. I'm finally getting my desired results!**

Answer (score 0):

`getIntent()` returns the `Intent` that was used to create the activity. In your case, that is the home screen launcher `Intent`.

When you scan the NFC tag, a new `Intent` will be delivered to that activity. That `Intent` is passed to an `onNewIntent()` method that you can override.

Depending on how your activity is being used, you might need to handle both cases:

- Where the user launched your app by scanning the NFC tag, so your activity was created with the NDEF `Intent`
- Where the user launched your app by other means before scanning the NFC tag, so your activity was created with some other `Intent` and you get the NDEF `Intent` in `onNewIntent()`

Comment: Seems like I was missing some information under my intent-filter tag, specifically the mimeType, as well as some random text/plain data in my NFC. I tried using onNewIntent() before having those things fixed and it didn't work as well. Thanks for the help anyway!